# How to fix Spring Boot Servlet Initializer error on Weblogic?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, weblogic, weblogic12c

I am getting "java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class" when I tried to deploy my Spring Boot application on weblogic.

If I remove the part of code which extends SpringBootServletInitializer, the file is deployed successfully. If I extend SpringBootServletInitializer, then it shows the error. How to fix it?

[image]

This is the error I receive:

[image]

This is my pom.xml

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpfJX.png)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add the code that is failing?

Comment: @delephin Please check the code and error above. Could you please help me with this?